# Integrate $\oint\frac{z}{\cos z-1}dz$ with residue theorem

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

$$\oint\limits_{|z-3|=4}^{}\frac{z}{\cos z-1}dz$$

My attempt:

$$\cos z=1$$

$$z=2\pi k$$

The set includes only $z=0$ and $z=2\pi$. What next?

Answer (score 1):

$$\DeclareMathOperator*{\res}{Res}
\oint_C\frac{z}{\cos z-1}\,dz=2\pi i\res_{z=0}\frac{z}{\cos z-1}+2\pi i\res_{z=2\pi}\frac{z}{\cos z-1}$$

Use the fact that around $z=0$ we have $$\cos(z)\simeq 1-\tfrac12z^2$$

Then $$\frac{z}{\cos z-1}\simeq \frac{z}{1-\tfrac12z^2-1}=-\frac{2}{z}$$
$$\res_{z=0}\frac{z}{\cos z-1}=\res_{z=0}\frac{-2}{z}=-2$$

And around $z=2\pi$:

$$\cos(z)\simeq 1-\tfrac12(z-2\pi)^2$$
$$\res_{z=2\pi}\frac{z}{\cos z-1}=\res_{z=2\pi}\frac{z}{1-\tfrac12(z-2\pi)^2-1}=-\res_{z=2\pi}\frac{2z-4\pi+4\pi}{(z-2\pi)^2}$$
$$=-2-\res_{z=2\pi}\frac{4\pi}{(z-2\pi)^2}=-2$$

Hence $$\oint_C\frac{z}{\cos z-1}\,dz=-8\pi i$$

#### Why does Taylor approximation work?

$$\cos(z)=1-\tfrac12z^2+\tfrac{1}{24}z^4+...$$
$$\frac{z}{\cos(z)-1}=\frac{z}{-\tfrac12z^2+\tfrac{1}{24}z^4+...}$$
$$=\frac{-2}{z-\tfrac{1}{12}z^3+...}=\frac{-2}{z(1-\tfrac{1}{12}z^2+...)}=g(z)$$

We can break this into

$$g(z)=\frac{A}{z}+\frac{f(z)}{1-\tfrac{1}{12}z^2+...}$$
$$-2\equiv A(1-\tfrac{1}{12}z^2+...)+z\cdot f(z)$$

Especially for $z=0$:
$$-2=A$$

So $$\res_{z=0} g(z)=\res_{z=0} \frac{-2}{z}+\res_{z=0}\frac{f(z)}{1-\tfrac{1}{12}z^2+...}=-2$$

Comment: You should explain why working with approximations leads to a mathematically correct answer.

Comment: @AlexM: the residue theorem allows integrals to be computed in terms of residues, which in turn are coefficients of a term in a Laurent expansion of a function - or, as you would put it, an approximation.

Comment: @RonGordon: I know what a Laurent series is, I also know the residue theorem. Note that in the answer the author does not expand the integrand as a Laurent series, he only does so with the denominator (he uses a truncation of Taylor's series for $\cos$). This might be correct, but a serious justification of this step is missing.

Comment: and without working with approximations, I just do not quite understand it, I only know the basic formula, I thought as we have second-order pole is necessary to look for the deduction by a limit, but I got very large calculation

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Res {$f(z),z=a$}=coefficient of $1/(z-a)$ in the expansion of $f(z)$ in powers of $(z-a)$.

In case of your question, it is not difficult to obtain the expansions of $f(z)$ in powers of $z$ and $(z-2π)$ as:

$f(z)=-2/z -z/6 +$ ..........

$f(z)=-4π/(z-2π)^2 -2/(z-2π)+$..........

From the above two expansions, the residue at each pole is $-2$. Then, by Cauchy's Residue theorem the given integral is $2πi×$Sum of residues at poles inside contour.

Answer (score 0):

The contour circles the singularities at $z=0$ and $z=2\pi$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{z}{\cos(z)-1}
&=\frac{z}{-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{24}+O\left(z^6\right)}\\
&=-\frac2z\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}{12}+O\left(z^4\right)}\\
&=-\frac2z-\frac z6+O\left(z^3\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the residue at $z=0$ is $-2$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(z-2\pi)+2\pi}{\cos(z-2\pi)-1}
&=\frac{(z-2\pi)+2\pi}{-\frac{(z-2\pi)^2}2+\frac{(z-2\pi)^4}{24}+O\left((z-2\pi)^6\right)}\\
&=-\left(\frac2{z-2\pi}+\frac{4\pi}{(z-2\pi)^2}\right)\frac1{1-\frac{(z-2\pi)^2}{12}+O\left((z-2\pi)^4\right)}\\
&=-\frac{4\pi}{(z-2\pi)^2}-\frac2{z-2\pi}-\frac\pi3-\frac{z-2\pi}6+O\left((z-2\pi)^2\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the residue at $z=2\pi$ is also $-2$.

Therefore, assuming the contour is counterclockwise, the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues, which is
$$
-8\pi i
$$